# Node js module how to get list of exported functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given a node js module/package, is there some way I can extract out all functions exported by that module ?

For example - if the module has a js file with following code:

```
exports.tokenizer = tokenizer;
exports.parse = parse;
exports.slice = slice;
exports.curry = curry;
```

Then I would like to have a following listed as exports: tokenizer, parse, slice, curry

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can require the file and just map through the object keys, which would return an array of the names of the exported objects.

```
var myExports = require('./exported-file.js');

console.log(Object.keys(myExports));
```

Answer (score 13):

Here's a quick and easy way:

```
console.dir(Object.keys(require('foo')));
```