# How to find filesystem path of an export of a Node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I'm working with a project that exports some functions from an `exports.js` file.

```js
// some-project/exports.js
export { loginFunction } from "./login/function"
export { registerFunction } from "./register/function"
```

I want to develop a tool that can import such a file and output the filesystem paths of all its exports. For example,

```js
const projectExports = require("some-project/exports")

const exportPaths = findExportPaths(projectExports)

console.log(exportPaths) // ["/Projects/some-project/login/function.js", "/Projects/some-project/register/function.js"]
```

How can I implement the functionality of `findExportPaths`?

I have tried the following methods/tools to accomplish this, but could not make them work:

- [Node js module how to get list of exported functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25529290/node-js-module-how-to-get-list-of-exported-functions)

  This gives me a list of all the exports, not their paths
- [In node.JS how can I get the path of a module I have loaded via require that is *not* mine (i.e. in some node_module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111163/in-node-js-how-can-i-get-the-path-of-a-module-i-have-loaded-via-require-that-is)

  This method suggests using `require.resolve()`, but that gives me the path of the module I'm importing. It does not provide paths of the exports of that module.
- [Vercel NFT](https://github.com/vercel/nft)

  I can't get it to provide paths of the exports of a file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: An export doesn't have a path.

Comment: I understand. Exploring options outside JS code, Is it possible for static analysis tools to find the path? Or would it be possible to attach one to it? Perhaps using some Typescript transformers or decorators magic?

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is trimming the name of the module from the string in require, then search it in the fileSystem with `fs.readDir` (if you're using nodejs) or similar ( https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback ) , then if found console.log the path

Comment: Interesting idea. It's not reliable enough for my needs, but I appreciate the input.

Comment: I've had some success with the [dependency-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-tree) module.